# Variable defined in do_local generates error: The variable ... is referenced before it is declared

Tags: python, class, object, namespaces

I am trying to understand namespaces in Python.

I tried this scenario as given in Python documentation.

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"
    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"
    do_local()
    print("before local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("before nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("before global assignment:", spam)

    spam = "test spam"

    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
```

This fails saying:

> The variable spam is referenced before its declared.

I have clearly defined the variable in the do_local().

Comment: `do_local` defines a local variable. It does not exist outside the scope of `do_local`.

Comment: Yea , You defined and its as its say local so this var is only visible in scope of `do_local()`

Answer (score 0):

I start with a simple case: I try to access a non-local variable that hasn't been defined anywhere. This will fail:

```
def scope_test1():

    # This function tries to access a non-local
    # variable spam. Since I never define spam,
    # this will cause an exception:
    # -> SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'spam' found
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"
```

This is easy enough to fix: I just have to add this variable in the appropriate scope:

```
def scope_test2():

    # This works:
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    spam = "test spam"
```

Now I want to add a local version of my function, to make things more interesting:

```
def scope_test3():

    # This function defines the variable spam, but
    # only locally, that is, it is not accesible from
    # outside
    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    # The functions do_local() gets executed and
    # creates an internal variable spam. This variable
    # isn’t visible from the outside.
    do_local()

    # So far, the variable spam hasn’t been declared.
    # So this will fail:
    # -> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spam' referenced before assignment
    print("after local assignment:", spam)

    # spam gets assigned here, but it’s too late
    spam = "test spam"
```

It fails again: it doesn't help that I define `spam` later (that's too late), and it also doesn't help that `do_local` assigns to `spam` locally: the function `scope_test3` doesn't see this local version.

I might try to remidy the situation by adding my non-local version:

```
def scope_test4():

    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    # Accesses a nonlocal variable spam when it gets called,
    # but doesn't add it, so it can’t save us.
    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    do_local()

    # So far, the variable spam still hasn’t been declared.
    # So this will still fail:
    # -> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'spam' referenced before assignment
    print("after local assignment:", spam)

    # spam gets assigned here, but it’s still too late
    spam = "test spam"
```

But that doesn't help either: `do_nonlocal` doesn't magically add `spam` to its nonlocal scope simply by existing.